# Elastic search - Return Unique values based on a filter/match

Tags: elasticsearch

```
PUT items/1
{ "language" : 10,
  "country" : "US" }

PUT items/2
{ "language" : 11,
  "country" : "UK" }

PUT items/3
{ "language" : 10,
  "country" : "US" }

PUT items/4
{ "language" : 12,
  "country" : "US" }
```

How do i write a search query that returns unique languages i.e., `10, 12` whose country is `US`

For getting a list of all unique languages `10,11,12` terms aggregation can be used. However, i am unable to figure out how to include the country filter into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the use-case one way to achieve this is using [filter aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) :
Example:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "country_us": {
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "country": "us"
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "language": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "language",
                  "size": 0
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```